# Running a .jar on Apache server, but out of memory error

Tags: java, spring, apache, memory, jar

I'd like to run a .jar on Apache server. (My host provides cPanel support and so on...)

When I try to run it with:

```
java -jar "JAR_FILE_PATH"
```

after a while I get the error:

> *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread*

I have also tried to run with `-Xmx16m - Xmx2G`, but I got the same error.

[image]

Maybe there are some cmds that I could configure the defaults with, but I am still noob, this is the first time...:)

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: "_I'd like to run a .jar on Apache server_" - please explain. [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) is a HTTP server. What does running a `.jar` have anything to do with it?

Comment: Okay, so this is a BE application that I worked on once. And of course, it has a FE side based on Angular 4. As far as I know, theoretically it could run on Apache. Or is it false?

Comment: That doesn't add any clarification. Apache serves files over HTTP - it can also run things via plugins - PHP, CGI etc. What does your `.jar` do and how does it fit in? If the question is how do I run a `.jar` on a server that also runs Apache, then the Apache part is surely irrelevant...

Comment: You most likely have bad code. Attach visual me to see what the threads are doing.

Comment: @BoristheSpider this is most likely a Tomcat.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen that was my thinking - but where would `java -jar` come into it?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, on my pc it works very well!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread` means you have not enough *native* memory to spawn a thread. Note, it is completely different thing from heap space.

The most typical case to get that error is to run out of stack space, address space or `max user processes`. Almost all of the cases are related with creating too many threads.

1. `stack space` on Linux can be checked via `ulimit -s`. Each Java thread consumes certain amount of stack size. It can be configured via `-Xss` or `-XX:ThreadStackSize=...`
   You can check the default stack size for your platform via `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize`. You can squeeze more threads by reducing `ThreadStackSize` at a cost of `StackOverflowError` in case your application would indeed require deep stacks.
2. `address space` is an issue in case you use 32bit JVM. As per your screenshot, you *are* using 32bit JVM, so you are limited with 4G total address space. That includes all the things (heap, non-heap, stack, native, etc memory). That is the more you allocate for heap (-Xmx) the less threads you can create.
   The workaround there is either use 64bit JVM, or **reduce** heap size, etc.
3. `max user processes` on Linux can be monitored via `ulimit -u`. In case you have "default" limit of 1000 processes, you can easily hit that as each thread counts toward that limit AFAIK. The solution there is to increase the limit.

In general, you likely want to add `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`, collect heap dump, and check the number of threads used. If the number of threads is sane (e.g. less than 100), then you want to check configuration (1-3 above). In case the number of threads is insane (e.g. exceeds 100), you might want to find a defect and fix that.